# change css attributes of child when parent class is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div inside another div. the parent has a particular class name that doesn't specifically have any css applied to it. the child element has css applied to it, specifically it's background color. so it looks like this...

```
<div id='myparent' class='someclass'>
    <div id='mychild' class='somebgcolor'></div>
</div>
```

what I want to do is change the background color of the child div when the class of the parent div is changed. so I'm changing the class of the parent with this javascript...

```
document.getElementById('myparent').className = 'someotherclass';
```

and in my css...

```
.someclass .somebgcolor {
    background-color: #369;
}
.someotherclass .somebgcolor {
    background-color: #401;
}
```

but it doesn't work. for starters, the initial background color isn't even applied, and no background color is applied when i update the class of the parent div. am i missing something fundamental to the way applying css to nested elements works?

Comment: It seems to be working for me. What kind of error message are you getting in your browser console?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2s9dg4L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything.  I just tried it out and it works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .someOtherClass {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .someOtherClass .someBgColor {
        background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myParent" class="someClass">
        <div id='myChild' class="someBgColor">
            asdasadasd
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var parent = document.getElementById('myParent');
        parent.className = "someOtherClass";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: huh, my bad. i've just implemented the same thing but in a slightly different way, but functionally the same as the question, and it seems to work fine now. i'm not sure why it wasn't working before, maybe had a syntax error in my code. will +1 and mark correct for your effort. thanks!